# Error "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Tags: android, excel, xml, android-studio, jxl

I have a code that worked well on eclipse and now I moved to Android Studio and there for some reason I cannot open the .xls file.

I am using jxl librariy, so I added the jar to the project's lib, and: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the manifest.
The code for opening the file is:

```
final String EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION = "src/exercise.xls";
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(EXCEL_FILE_LOCATION));
```

The file and the directory both exist for sure and yet it throws the exeption `W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/exercise.xls: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which android version are you using

Comment: Do you mean the API?

Comment: yes what is your android api level

Comment: on my phone it's 10, tried running it on 27 in the amulator and it didn't work either

Comment: i had same problem on Android 10 and below 10 its working fine. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage this might help you i am also in same search .